# Space to the right of the table

Tags: tabularx

Not really sure why there is a space at the right hand side of the following table. Also the numbers inside the table should be shifted a bit to the left.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
        \caption{ Tests}
         \label{tbl:GCtest}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llllllll}
                \hline
                &  \multicolumn{7}{c}{Volume}\\  \hline 
                &  & Whole & Manfacturing & Construction & Retail Trade & Services & Financials\\  
                \hline 
                \multirow{14}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Sector}} & Market & 0.02** &  &  &  &  & 0.08* \\
                & (x) & 0.13 &  &  &  &  & 0.10*\\
                & Manfacturing & 0.00*** & 0.01*** &  &  &  & 0.05** \\
                & (x) & 0.01*** & 0.04** &  &  &  & 0.04** \\
                & Construction & 0.55 &  & 0.07* &  &  & 0.28 \\
                & (r ) & 0.32 &  & 0.10* &  &  & 0.60 \\
                & Retail Trade & 0.88 &  &  & 0.16 &  & 0.70 \\
                & (r ) & 0.01*** &  &  & 0.01*** &  & 0.01*** \\
                & Services & 0.10* &  &  &  & 0.09* & 0.18 \\
                & (r) & 0.00*** &  &  &  & 0.1* & 0.01*** \\
                & Services [wald test] & 0.46 &  &  &  & 0.12 & 0.81\\
                & (r )[wald test] & 0.00*** &  &  &  & 0.03** & 0.02** \\
                & Consumer & 0.67 & 0.58 & 0.76 & 0.16 & 0.22 & 0.21 \\
                & (r ) & 0.03** & 0.04** & 0.29 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.01*** \\ 
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}
            \scriptsize Level of significance for correlation coefficients are ***  0.001, ** 0.01, *0.05
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You're using  a `tabularx` environment, with width set to `\linewidth`, yet you're using only `l`-type columns. Consider using `X` as the type for the final six columns.

Comment: @Mico I have just done that and the space disappeared, however, spaces are different between columns.

Comment: Actually, with `X` columns you're *guaranteed* to get columns that are equally wide. However, this might not be apparent if the column headers have wildly differing widths (as is the case in your table. In such a case, you may be better off using a `tabular*` environment. (I'll post an answer showing how this might be done.)

Comment: @Mice that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have only columns of type `l` in your `tabularx` environment. If you replace the six final `l` column specifiers with `X`, you'll find that the columns now "fill" out the available space. By construction, the six `X` columns will be equally wide.

However, the `X` columns may not *appear to be* equally wide, as the column headers vary considerably in length and the columns themselves are quite "sparse". Thus, rather than making the columns equally wide, you may want to make the *gaps between adjacent headers* equally wide. This may be achieved by using a `tabular*` environment instead of the current `tabularx` environment.

Incidentally, in my experience, people strongly dislike having to crane their necks to read material that's been rotated 90 degrees from the other material. In the code below, I've taken the liberty of combining the first two columns, relieving readers from neck-craning. I trust the table's readability hasn't suffered as result of this change.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,tabularx,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{More Tests} \label{tbl:more}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let tabular* find optimal intercolumn space
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} llllll }
\hline
Sector &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Volume}\\  
\cline{2-7}
& Wholesale & Manfacturing & Construction & Retail Trade & Services & Financials\\  
\hline 
Market & 0.02** &  &  &  &  & 0.08* \\
(x) & 0.13 &  &  &  &  & 0.10*\\
Manfacturing & 0.00*** & 0.01*** &  &  &  & 0.05** \\
(x) & 0.01*** & 0.04** &  &  &  & 0.04** \\
Construction & 0.55 &  & 0.07* &  &  & 0.28 \\
(r ) & 0.32 &  & 0.10* &  &  & 0.60 \\
Retail Trade & 0.88 &  &  & 0.16 &  & 0.70 \\
(r ) & 0.01*** &  &  & 0.01*** &  & 0.01*** \\
Services & 0.10* &  &  &  & 0.09* & 0.18 \\
(r ) & 0.00*** &  &  &  & 0.1* & 0.01*** \\
Services [wald test] & 0.46 &  &  &  & 0.12 & 0.81\\
(r )[wald test] & 0.00*** &  &  &  & 0.03** & 0.02** \\
Consumer & 0.67 & 0.58 & 0.76 & 0.16 & 0.22 & 0.21 \\
(r ) & 0.03** & 0.04** & 0.29 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.01*** \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Level of significance for correlation coefficients: ***  0.001, ** 0.01, *0.05}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To make the numbers centered in their respective columns, as well as aligned on the decimal markers, you could load the `dcolumn` package and define a column type named `d` for the six of the seven columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,tabularx,caption}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}  % align numbers on decimal markers
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{More Tests} \label{tbl:more}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX find optimal intercolumn space
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{d{1.3}} }
\hline
Sector &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Volume}\\  
\cline{2-7}
& \mc{Wholesale} & \mc{Manfacturing} & \mc{Construction} & \mc{Retail Trade} & \mc{Services} & \mc{Financials}\\  
\hline 
Market & 0.02^{**} &  &  &  &  & 0.08^{*} \\
(x) & 0.13 &  &  &  &  & 0.10^{*}\\
Manfacturing & 0.00^{***} & 0.01^{***} &  &  &  & 0.05^{**} \\
(x) & 0.01^{***} & 0.04^{**} &  &  &  & 0.04^{**} \\
Construction & 0.55 &  & 0.07^{*} &  &  & 0.28 \\
(r ) & 0.32 &  & 0.10^{*} &  &  & 0.60 \\
Retail Trade & 0.88 &  &  & 0.16 &  & 0.70 \\
(r ) & 0.01^{***} &  &  & 0.01^{***} &  & 0.01^{***} \\
Services & 0.10^{*} &  &  &  & 0.09^{*} & 0.18 \\
(r ) & 0.00^{***} &  &  &  & 0.1^{*} & 0.01^{***} \\
Services [wald test] & 0.46 &  &  &  & 0.12 & 0.81\\
(r )[wald test] & 0.00^{***} &  &  &  & 0.03^{**} & 0.02^{**} \\
Consumer & 0.67 & 0.58 & 0.76 & 0.16 & 0.22 & 0.21 \\
(r ) & 0.03^{**} & 0.04^{**} & 0.29 & 0.15 & 0.33 & 0.01^{***} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Level of significance for correlation coefficients: ${}^{***}$  0.001, ${}^{**}$ 0.01, ${}^{*}$ 0.05}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really an elegant solution. I liked combining the first two columns. Any suggestions for indenting values inside the table?

Comment: @AhmedSalhin - Thanks for the compliment! I'm afraid I don't quite get what you mean by "indenting values inside the table". Please elaborate.

Comment: What I mean is that the numbers are left aligned to each other in every columns. I just want them to be shifted a bit to the right like you adding couple of white spaces before each number. In other words, I need the header of each column, like Financial, to be cantered above the numbers vector below it. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: @AhmedSalhin - Thanks for this clarification. I'll post an addendum to show how the numbers can be centered in the column (and aligned on the decimal markers).

Comment: Thanks Mico. Your clarification of the problemis even better.